# Which video cards play nice with 14.04 and 2 monitors?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, multiple-monitors

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu and I'm totally hooked... but, I cannot get a GeForce 8400GS to work with 14.04 and 2 identical monitors - extended desktop. I've all but given up and I've spent days looking for a solution. From my search for a fix it appears to be quite a few problems with older Nvidia, 2 monitors and Ubuntu.

If I don't find a solution soon, I'm going to try another video card.

**So, my question is what other - low end - cards will work with Ubuntu and 2 monitors?** I'm looking for a reasonably certain out of the box solution.

The setup is entirely for web browsing and and limited photo resizing and so on, no heavy graphics need and I'm not worried about super speed.

Thanks, and once again - any and all help, advice and questions are welcome.

Comment: I replaced a *geforce 8300GS* (OEM only) with a *MSI Radeon HD 6450 R6450-MD1GD3H 1 Go*. It is low power (300W is enough), passively cooled (no fan), very tiny (feat in my mini-atx inspiron 15 box) and with HDMI+DVI+VGA output. However, price have increased since I bought it a year ago. Look at other HD 6450 card ?

Comment: Did you have any trouble getting both monitors recognized at the correct resolutions? What outputs did you use? VGA and DVI? Did you use an adapter for the DVI? Thanks for the direction.

Comment: No problem with 15.04 and open source ati driver. I used the DVI and HDMI output without adapter. But you don't have to worry so much about it. It should work.... HDMI to DVI adapter cause no problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a GT630 with dual monitors which works very good. The one thing with nvidia and Ubuntu is the sluggish UI which you'll have to fix by setting the [grub boot parameter](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/127563):
`video=LVDS-1:d`

I don't know why Ubuntu don't fix this boot parameter by default, but it is what it is. Simple fix to an annoying problem.